# Redirect to subdirectory not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

http://mydomain.com/ is set to a folder that looks like this:

```
/app/
/web/
    /assets/
    /.../
    /index.php
/.htaccess
```

In the `.htaccess` on my Apache 2.2 server I want to redirect all requests to `/web`, and if not an existing file under `/web` redirect to `/web/index.php`.

So far I have:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ /web/$1 [N]

RewriteBase /web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

In my understanding this means:

1. Turn rewrite engine on
2. Match anything and prepend the request with `/web/`
3. Match anything that is not a valid filename under `/web` and redirect it with query string attached to `/web/index.php`

This redirects to `/web/index.php` fine, but the other requests to files under `/web/` don't get served correctly.

Any explanation as to why this is? The RewriteLog I am getting is rather elusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to retain the matched string, you need to have have an expression in parentheses. $1 matches the first expression in parentheses, $2 the second, etc.

Also, the [N] flag will cause your rule to be run repeatedly until it doesn't match anything. You might want to avoid that with this type of rewrite (because loops). Great info at [apache.org docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^((?!web/).*)$ /web/$1

RewriteBase /web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /web/index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^((?!web/).*)$ /web/$1 [L,NC]
```